# Getting a list index out of range, while being able to print the exact index

Tags: python, list, split, readline, indexoutofrangeexception

I am writing some simple code to read in a file by line and split the lines. I can create a variable to hold each line as a list. I can then print each index of said list, but I am unable to assign the index to a new variable. Below is the example code.

```
fileList = [ f for f in os.listdir(outputDir) if f.endswith(".txt") ]

    for dayFile in fileList:
       print dayFile
       with open(outputDir+dayFile) as openDayFile:
            for line in openDayFile.readlines():
                print line
```

If I simply print the line I get.

```
20.20  -100.36  0.60

26.98  -102.06  0.00

19.36  -90.72  0.00

16.65  -95.93  0.00
```

If I add in .

```
Three = line.split()
print Three
```

Gives me.

```
['20.20', '-100.36', '0.60']
['26.98', '-102.06', '0.00']
['19.36', '-90.72', '0.00'] etc...
```

Now when I assign

```
A= Three[0] #there is no error.
```

When I assign

```
A = Three[1]
```

or  A= Three[2]

I get the error.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I simply do

```
print Three[1]
```

It prints...

```
-100.36
-102.06
-90.72
-95.93
-99.12
-97.93
-96.72
-96.10
-100.93
-98.14
```

Can anybody help me understand what the issue is?

Comment: Is there any line in the file which doesn't have 3 values?

Comment: No each line has 3  values.

Comment: Just for test could you `print len(Three)` and check.

Comment: I just did this and found the issue smh, The file i want to eventually write was previously written and not removed with just a header. This file was being read in with the others as part of the process.

Comment: That's great! so your problem is solved.

Comment: Yes thank you and smh at myself.